# Failed to select a option value with whitespace in a multiselect using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<select id="subjectsPassed" name="subjects_passed[]" data-width="100%">
    <option value="Hindi">Hindi</option>
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="Math">Math</option>
    <option value="Science">Science</option>
    <option value="Social Science">Social Science</option>
    <option value="Sanskrit">Sanskrit</option>
</select>
```

I Have a string of Subjects, the subject with whitespace is failed to get selected

using javaScript

```
var hidValue = 'Hindi, English, Math, Science, Social Science, Sanskrit';
var optionVal = [];
var selectedOptions = hidValue.split(/\s*(?:,|$)\s*/);
for(var i in selectedOptions) {
 optionVal[i]= selectedOptions[i];    
}
optionVal.forEach(myFunc);
function myFunc(value){
 $("#subjectsPassed option[value="+value+"]").prop("selected", true);
}
$("#subjectsPassed").multiselect('reload');
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz1Xb.png)

Please give a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector should have the attribute value in double quotes. So change:

```
 $("#subjectsPassed option[value="+value+"]")
```

To:

```
 $('#subjectsPassed option[value="'+value+'"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

jack

To make your solution work just add a pair of single quotes here:

```
function myFunc(value) {
  $("#subjectsPassed option[value='" + value + "']").prop("selected", true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sandro. You know, I have ruined 3 hours for this small change